# Maths behind sliding scale pricing

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to work out a simple calculation for the following:

a phone model has the maximum sale price of £85.00 and this is if only 1 unit is purchased and a minimum sales price of £50.00 - this is if 150 units and over are purchased in one.

How can I work out a way of the price if between 2 and 149 units are purchased??

Thanks,
B.

Comment: Is there a linear relationship?

Comment: Sounds like homework. How do you think you ought to handle it?

Comment: Should be on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually, this should not be on any SE site, without more details. Currently, we have no way to know which sliding scale formula to apply.

Comment: Why is there a Maths tags then?!?!?!?

Comment: You may be 30, but this is a very elementary question for both math and programming.

Comment: There's no way. Different vendors have different ways to compute price as a function of order size. One thing I can say for sure: I've never known any company to use a linear scale for concrete objects like others are suggesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formula:

```
Y = 50 + ((85 - 50) / (150 - 1)) * (X - 1)
```

Result:

```
X = 1    -->   Y = 85
X = 33   -->   Y = 57.52
X = 150  -->   Y = 50
```

Comment: Thanks Anne, this is what I was looking for!!!!! Don't know why everyone else was grumbling....

Comment: Why mark me down, when other people had all the info to answer the question - too quick to judge on here!!!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is devoted to programming related questions. Strictly, your question is a mathematical problem. The community is quite harsh in terms of closing and down-voting unrelated questions. It keeps the website clean though. I can understand it feels unpleasant since your question was honest. Anyways, I'm happy this worked for you! Don't worry too much about the down-vote :)

Comment: I think the above is in fact wrong. It should be: Y = 85 - (85 - 50) / (150 - 1) * (X - 1)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have a linear model in such situations. I don't know the right English term, but you would have more like a piecewise or stepwise function here.

But nevertheless, you can get a linear function through [**interpolation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).